# How can Junit test classes detect classes defined in a kotlin file?

Tags: java, kotlin, junit, junit5

I have a Java gradle project in which i'm using a kotlin file to easily define pojo-like classes on one line. However, when i try to start a junit5 test I get a compile error stating that it can't detect any of the classes defined in the kotlin file. I have the kotlin plugin included in the gradle.build file. How do i get the test classes to detect the classes defined in the kotlin file?

Thank you

Comment: Are your tests in Java?

Comment: as you use Gradle and JUnit5, did you add `useJUnitPlatform()` to the test task? Do you have a custom `@Test`-annotation?

Comment: Can you post your gradle file ? It sounds like your data(?) classes aren't being compiled.

Comment: @MaxFarsikov yes.

Comment: @Roland no didnt add useJUnitPlatform() but i did add `@Test` annotation

Comment: @FAM_Maurice I recommend adding `useJUnitPlatform()`... that way it will work as you expect....

Answer (score 1):

If you write JUnit5-tests with Gradle, be sure to have something like the following in place in your build.gradle-(or build.gradle.kts)-file, so that Gradle also knows that it should use the JUnit5-platform (compare also [JUnit 5 User Guide - Build support - Gradle](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-gradle)):

```
tasks.withType<Test> {
  useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Moreover also ensure that the annotation you use is the following:

```
org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
```

and not the one of JUnit4, i.e. `org.junit.Test`. If you have that one, you probably want to remove the junit4-dependency altogether.